# Angular2-Meteor zone() method

Tags: meteor, angular, rxjs, angular-meteor, rxjs5

In the angular2-meteor tutorial [step3](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding), we use a zone method.
Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Parties } from '../../both/collections/parties.collection';

...some lines skipped...
  template
})
export class AppComponent {
  parties: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.parties = Parties.find({}).zone();
  }
}
```

What exactly does Parties.find({}).zone() do?

Answer (score 5):

According to the article you linked:

> `.zone()` is a wrapper for the regular `Observable` that connects the collections changes to the view using the Component's Zone.

For more information, [here is an article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) that goes in depth into what Zones are in Angular 2.

Essentially, `Parties.find({}).zone()` will `.find()` all data in the `Parties` collection and connect that data to the components Zone. Since the mongo collection is a reactive data source, this should allow the component to reactively update its data as the data is updated in the Mongo collection.